# Exporting CSV File with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: javascript, csv, encoding, export

This is what I use to export a HTML table into csv and download it:

```
exportCSVFile: function (object) {
    var processRow = function (row) {
        var finalVal = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            var result = row[j];
            if (j > 0) {
                finalVal += ';';
            }
            finalVal += result;
        }
        return finalVal + '\n';
    };

    const {filename, table} = object;
    var csvFile = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        csvFile += processRow(table[i]);
    }

    csvFile = new Blob([csvFile], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'});
    var downloadCSV;
    downloadCSV = document.createElement('a');
    downloadCSV.download = filename;
    downloadCSV.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
    downloadCSV.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadCSV);
    downloadCSV.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadCSV);
},
```

It works perfectly well when export an English document, but when I try to export a French document with special characters like (é, è, ç, ...), I get &eacute, &egrave...

Looking in SO, I found that some were able to get past this problem by adding the prefix `\uFEFF, but unfortunately that didn't work for me.

Does anyone have idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to find an answer to my problem. What I did was, I wrote another function that decodes HTML character entities by replacing the HTML code with their key.

For example:

`Pr&eacute;paration` becomes `préparation`.
Here's the function in question:

```
decode: function(string) {
    var map = {
        '"': '&quot;',
        'à' : '&agrave;',
        'á' : '&aacute;',
        'â' : '&acirc;',
        'ã' : '&atilde;',
        'ä' : '&auml;',
        'å' : '&aring;',
        'æ' : '&aelig;',
        'ç' : '&ccedil;',
        'è' : '&egrave;',
        'é' : '&eacute;',
        'ê' : '&ecirc;',
        'ë' : '&euml;',
        'ì' : '&igrave;',
        'í' : '&iacute;',
        'î' : '&icirc;',
        'ï' : '&iuml;',
        'À' : '&Agrave;',
        'Á' : '&Aacute;',
        'Â' : '&Acirc;',
        'Ã' : '&Atilde;',
        'Ä' : '&Auml;',
        'Å' : '&Aring;',
        'Æ' : '&AElig;',
        'Ç' : '&Ccedil;',
        'È' : '&Egrave;',
        'É' : '&Eacute;',
        'Ê' : '&Ecirc;',
        'Ë' : '&Euml;',
        'Ì' : '&Igrave;',
        'Í' : '&Iacute;',
        'Î' : '&Icirc;',
        'Ï' : '&Iuml;',
        '\'' : '&apos;'

    };
    var entityMap = map;
    for (var key in entityMap) {
        var entity = entityMap[key];
        var regex = new RegExp(entity, 'g');
        string = string.replace(regex, key);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Then I just called it in the OP code right before returning the final value:

```
finalVal = DecodeUtils.decode(finalVal);            
return finalVal + '\n';
```

That's it. I hope it'll help someone else with a similar problem.